# ServiceStack.OrmLite with a DateTime.Month Predicate

Tags: predicate, ormlite-servicestack

While using ServiceStack.OrmLite 3.9.70.0, and following some of the examples from the [ServiceStack.OrmLite wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/wiki/Release-Notes).

I am trying to select rows where the LastActivity date month = 1.

I keep getting the error:

`{"variable 'pp' of type 'Author' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined"}`

LastActivity is a nullable DateTime, defind like:

`public DateTime ? LastActivity  { get; set;}`

I have tried:

    `db.Select<Author>(q => q.LastActivity.Value.Month == 1);`

AND

`var visitor = db.CreateExpression<Author>();

db.Select<Author>(visitor.Where(q => q.LastActivity.Value.Month == 1));`

AND

`SqlExpressionVisitor<Author> ev = OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.ExpressionVisitor<Author>();


db.Select<Author>(ev.Where(q => q.LastActivity.Value.Month == 1));`

AND

`var predicate = ServiceStack.OrmLite.PredicateBuilder.True<Author>();

predicate = predicate.And(q => q.LastActivity.Value.Month == 1);


db.Select<Author>(predicate);`

I am trying to avoid using a sql string in the select because I like the compile time checking of the field names and types.

Answer (score 0):

do a less than and more than on the date field IE

```
LastActivity >= variableThatHoldsStartDateOfMonth && LastActivity <= VariableThatHoldsLastDayOfMOnth.
```

This will give you results for the whole month